# How do I specify many utxo in a bitcoin cash transaction?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, node.js

I want to create a Tx with bitcoincashjs:
[create-a-transaction](https://github.com/bitcoincashjs/bitcoincashjs/blob/master/docs/examples.md#create-a-transaction)
But how do I specify multi inputs: from(utxo) and multi outputs: to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const bch = require('bitcoincashjs');

const privateKey = new bch.PrivateKey('L1uyy5qTuGrVXrmrsvHWHgVzW9kKdrp27wBC7Vs6nZDTF2BRUVwy');
const utxos = [{
  'txId' : '115e8f72f39fad874cfab0deed11a80f24f967a84079fb56ddf53ea02e308986',
  'outputIndex' : 0,
  'address' : '17XBj6iFEsf8kzDMGQk5ghZipxX49VXuaV',
  'script' : '76a91447862fe165e6121af80d5dde1ecb478ed170565b88ac',
  'satoshis' : 50000
}, {
  'txId' : '115e8f72f39fad874cfab0deed11a80f24f967a84079fb56ddf53ea02e308986',
  'outputIndex' : 0,
  'address' : '17XBj6iFEsf8kzDMGQk5ghZipxX49VXuaV',
  'script' : '76a91447862fe165e6121af80d5dde1ecb478ed170565b88ac',
  'satoshis' : 50000
}];
const transaction = new bch.Transaction()
  .from(utxos)
  .to('1Gokm82v6DmtwKEB8AiVhm82hyFSsEvBDK', 15000)
  .sign(privateKey);

console.log(transaction.toString())
```

> `from`: A high level interface to add an input from a UTXO. It has a series of variants:
>
> `from(utxo)`: add an input from an Unspent Transaction Output. Currently, only P2PKH outputs are supported.
>
> `from(utxos)`: same as above, but passing in an array of Unspent Outputs.
>
> `from(utxo, publicKeys, threshold)`: add an input that spends a UTXO with a P2SH output for a Multisig script. The publicKeys argument is an array of public keys, and threshold is the number of required signatures in the Multisig script.

Details: https://bitcore.io/api/lib/transaction#adding-inputs